# How can I update the same line in several different files?

Tags: perl

I have a dozen or so Perl files with this line:

```
my $version = "<span class=\"foottext\"><em>version 0.11</em></span>";
```

This is line 7 of each perl file. The element I need to batch-modify is "X.XX" -- the version number.

What is the most elegant script I can run from the shell (in Perl) to open each file, change the version number on line 7, and then write the file?

Comment: Perl won't beat `sed` here: `sed -ri '7s/(version) [0-9]\.[0-9]{2}/\1 your_new_version/' files`. If you want to use some more sophisticated version changing algorithm, then I would use `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=perl+change+line+multiple+files) reveals that the following one-liner should help:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/version 0\.11/version 0.12/g;' *.pl
```

On a more general note, you should **avoid code duplication** and move that line into one (single) library file that is called by your dozen other files.

Comment: Thanks, I've just started learning -- I'll start reading up on calling library files now.

Comment: You might also consider not mixing presentation with code. Move all of that HTML to some sort of templating system.